# C# Interface Implementation Parameter Type Confusion

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm working on a set of microservices built using Azure Functions which each contain a set of endpoints representing CRUD operations.  Each of these microservices is doing largely the same operations on varying entities.  It occurred to me that we could define a service interface like the following to specify an implementing class representing the business logic for each of these endpoints.  The idea is to define the basic functions of the service such that it can be used with whatever type of data we are working with in that particular microservice.  The service interface is as follows:

```
    public interface IManagerService
    {
        public Task<IResponse> List(IDataRetrievalRequest filter, HttpRequest request, int offset, int limit);
        public Task<IResponse> Detail(List<int> ids);
        public Task<IResponse> Create(IDataChangeRequest createRequest);
        public Task<IResponse> Update(IDataChangeRequest updateRequest);
        public Task<IResponse> Delete(IDataChangeRequest deleteRequest);
    }
```

As parameters for all of these methods I have the following interfaces defined:

```
    public interface IDataChangeRequest
    {
        public List<T> Deserialize<T>(HttpRequest request);
    }
```

```
    public interface IDataRetrievalRequest
    {
        public T Deserialize<T>(HttpRequest request);
    }
```

When I attempt to implement the service interface I am trying to use a method like the following:

```
    public async Task<ListDataType> List(
            SearchFilter filter,
            HttpRequest req,
            int offset,
            int limit)
        {
            try
            {
                // code for retrieving some data.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

In this case "SearchFilter" is a class which implements the "IDataRetrievalRequest" interface.

```
    public class SearchFilter : IDataRetrievalRequest
    {
         public Filter Deserialize<Filter>(HttpRequest request)
         {
             var filter = // code to Perform deserialization.
             return filter;
         }
    }
```

I'm having two problems with this,

1:  on the service interface implementation I cannot use the SearchFilter class as a parameter or that method is no longer considered to be implementing the interface method in question.  My understanding of this is that if the concrete class implements the interface it should satisfy the type requirement, so I'm relatively confused as to why this doesn't work.

2: On the SearchFilter class, the "return filter;" statement indicates an error stating: "Cannot implicitly convert from FullyQualifiedPathTo.Filter to Filter" which fairly clearly indicates that the type parameter is not pointing to the appropriate type, however I'm unclear as to why that is.  I've attempted to fix this a number of ways including making the IDataRetrievalRequest interface generic, however I then have the problem of needing to make the "List" method of the interface generic as well in order to pass a type to the IDataRetrievalRequest which then creates the first problem I described above in this scenario as well.

I've been at this a while and I'm rather confused so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use OData or GraphQL? Why do you want to write your own service and repository and query layer, why don't you spend your time on what makes your application unique?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot implement interface with derived types but you can change your interface to be generic and then you should be able to achieve what you want
or you can use on trick you will need 2 interfaces and abstract type,
the idea is to have runtime not generic type but on compile time generic

```
public interface IManagerService
{

 public Task<IResponse> Create(IDataChangeRequest createRequest);

}
public interface IManagerService<TResponse, TDataChangeRequest> 
:IManagerService where TResponse : IResponse
where TDataChangeRequest : IDataChangeRequest
{

  public Task<TResponse> Create(TDataChangeRequest createRequest);

 }

 public abstract class  ManagerService<TResponse, TDataChangeRequest> : IManagerService<TResponse, TDataChangeRequest> 
where TResponse : IResponse 
where TDataChangeRequest : IDataChangeRequest
{
    public abstract Task<TResponse> Create(TDataChangeRequest createRequest);

   public Task<IResponse> Create(IDataChangeRequest createRequest)
  {
    return Create(createRequest);
  }
 }
```

then implementation will look like

```
class ManagerServiceImpl : ManagerService<SomeResponse, SomeDataChangeRequest> 

 {
      public async Task<IResponse> Create(IDataChangeRequest 
  createRequest)
   {
    return await Create((TDataChangeRequest)createRequest);
   }
}
```

at runtime you can use non-generic interface now IManagerService